# apply several arguments R unused arguments

Tags: r, apply

Im trying to run a phillips test to several subsets of data (row and columns).
When running a single pp.test function, everything works easy:

```
pp.test(GDP[GDP$iso2c == "NG","logrGDP"])
```

but when ich try to run the code on a selected list of variables and CNTR:

```
  select_varab <- colnames(GDP)[5:length(GDP)]
CNTR <- c("NG", "AO")
    pp_test_fct <- function(x,y) {pp.test(GDP[GDP$iso2c == x,y])}
    test <- sapply(CNTR_main , pp_test_fct, y= selct_varab)
```

I recieve the error term: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
unused argument (y = c("logrGDP"...

**EDIT: After adding ,y in the function (thanks to @benson23) I recieve the error: Error in pp.test(GDP[GDP$iso2c == x, y]) :
x is not a vector or univariate time series. So subset did not seem to work proper.**

I appreciate any comment.

```
dput(head(GDP[1:10]))
structure(list(iso2c = c("BF", "BI", "BJ", "BW", "CF", "CG"), 
    date = c(1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980), rM1 = c(1661947554.96311, 
    1019597585.62243, 3478933419.80619, 61141256.3369008, 1126506157.35666, 
    2664160161.20273), rGDP = c(12725808921, 8558552507.7, 17021782080, 
    212843126.372505, 5178489999.99999, 15581249243), logrM1 = c(21.2312559775046, 
    20.742673862498, 21.9699915951941, 17.9286974227422, 20.8423867837397, 
    21.703154708389), logrGDP = c(23.2668979667928, 22.8701969132334, 
    23.5577596596633, 19.1760659564236, 22.3677793449302, 23.4693340566521
    ), GDP_deflator_linked_series = c(46.9449484954342, 17.6934742440481, 
    31.5204429286927, 11.2702992078302, 68.3735323564527, 33.3634283130628
    ), Inflation_consumer_prices = c(12.2026364968298, 2.49851950030163, 
    1.08298150398196, 13.6324251470895, 1.35448615828445, 4.10605287486481
    ), Mobile_cellular_subscriptions = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Individuals_using_the_Internet = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, -1.49035680578891e-05)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thanks. that was an obvious mistake. sadly i recieve the error Error in pp.test(GDP[GDP$iso2c == x, y]) :
x is not a vector or univariate time series than, where conclude that subset is not properly working.

Comment: I cannot test it because there is neither "NG" nor "AO" in your sample data. Also there're quite some typos in your code (`select_varab` vs  `selct_varab`, `CNTR` vs `CNTR_main`)